# is it possible to use a string variable as a tag in xquery

Tags: xquery, webharvest

Can I use something like following in xquery? Basically I want to use string variable as a tag. I am using web harvest to extract data. Any help or pointers appreciated.

```
declare variable $doc as node() external;
declare variable $tag as xs:string;
let $tag := $doc//div[@class=details]//tr[1]/td[1]
return 
    <$tag>{$doc//div[@class=details]//tr[1]/td[2]</$tag>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the element constructor `element { $tag } { $content }`.

There are two additional problems with your query:

- No need for declaring `$tag` as a variable, you're hiding it anyway
- Missing closing curly brackets in front of the end tag

This code should work in quite everything but MSSQL which does not support variable names in element constructor's tag name fields:

```
declare variable $doc as node() external;

let $tag := $doc//div[@class=details]//tr[1]/td[1]
return 
    element { $tag } { $doc//div[@class=details]//tr[1]/td[2] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible with the element {} construction:

```
return element {$tag} {$doc//div[@class=details]//tr[1]/td[2]}
```